# How to find the 'Instance ID' for PowerShell Invoke-TroubleshootingPack?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I was doing a PowerShell training, that said use the PowerShell help to run a "Networking troubleshooting pack"

I found, ran and read

```
Get-Help Get-TroubleshootingPack -full
Get-Help Invoke-TroubleshootingPack -full
Get-Help about_Remote_Troubleshooting -full
```

Thinking I had it mostly figured out I ran

```
PS C:\> Get-TroubleshootingPack -Path 'C:\Windows\diagnostics\system\Networking' | Invoke-TroubleshootingPack
```

And that gives me

```
Starting network diagnostics... 

Instance ID
Not to be specified outside of MSDT application.
:
```

So I enter the Instance

```
MSSQLSERVER
```

And that gets me this error

Invoke-TroubleshootingPack : An error occurred when running a PowerShell script. (Exception from HRESULT: 
0x803C0101)
At line:1 char:76
+ Get-TroubleshootingPack -Path "C:\Windows\diagnostics\system\Networking" | Invok ...
+                                                                            ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Windows.Diagnosis.DiagPack:DiagPack) [Invoke-Trou 
   bleshootingPack], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PackageDiagnoseFailed,Microsoft.Windows.Diagnosis.Commands.InvokeTroubleshoot 
   ingPack

I try several options for the Instance ID: Server Name, IP, 0, 1. They all give the same error

Then I go looking for a way to identify the Instance ID, I find the two questions below but they don't give me anything to get around the error.

- [SQL Server - difference between instance name and instance id](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58014)
- [SQL Server Instance ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353520)

I search some more and found [This Blog](https://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/windows-7-troubleshooting-pack/) which is giving step by step to do everything I already figured out.  It shows the place to enter the Instance ID. But gives no clue what the value should be.  More searching just, leads to more frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to enter a 'Instance ID' for PowerShell Invoke-TroubleshootingPack

Just hit enter, when prompted for the Instance ID, without a value.

After I figured it out, I went back and looked at the training directions and found the following hiding in the middle of the paragraph.

> you’ll be asked for an “Instance ID.” Hit Enter

I learned a lot on this journey, this was frustrating. Posting so others will find the answer sooner than I did.